# Header precendence: Apache Vs. PHP specific to cache-control & expires

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cache

My companies production dynamic web servers ( Apache + PHP 5.1x) are using the Apache expires module and there is a clause inside http.conf as follows:

```
<FilesMatch ".+">
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "A0"
</FilesMatch>
```

If I were to set inside a php script "Cache-Control" and "Expires", would it get eaten by this clause?

Normally I would test this on my own but having trouble convincing the Expires module to function on my workstation and the company Admin's are down at the data-center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making this answer/question community wiki.   PHP does overrule Apache in regards to mod_expire.